# MongoDB fulltext search for common words

Tags: mongodb

Hi i have a big problem with full text search, i have a collection with 10 million of documents that has lot of common words in the indexed field for example: what, as, like, how, hi, hello, etc.

When i do a serch with the word "hi" the search becomes super slow and takes about 30 minutes to search the results, and on the other hand when i do the same but with a uncommon word the search is super faster and takes less than 30 ms.
i don´t know what can be the problem.

My text index:

```
db.themes.createIndex({"theme":"text"})
```

and the query that i run:

```
db.themes.find({$text: {$search: "hi"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}}).limit(20)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to limit the number of documents you are going to search on beforehand?  See here:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/

Answer (score 0):

well that's how it is. though mongodb provides full text capabilities but the performance is not on par with popular text search engines.

you probably can find in internet that most implementations have elastic search implemented along with mongodb for search optimizations. you can either use elastic search or Solr for your operations.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's text search is disgracefully slow on large collections. I also don't like its way of automatically thinking that "James Bond" is OR, but that's another story... (for AND, need to search for "\"James\" \"Bond\"" which is inelegant at best).

One way to go around it, if your application allows it, is to [Limit the Number of Entries Scanned](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/) by filtering on other fields. For that, it **needs** to be an equality, it can't be $gt or such. You might have to be creative to solve that... I've grouped my cities in "metropolitan areas" (this took a while...), and now I can search by {metro: "DC", {$text: {$search: "pizza"}}.